# LDAP Authentication using VBA in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, authentication, vba, ldap

I am creating an Access project linked to a SQL Server. Instead of using Windows authentication for the SQL Server I want to use an application specific username/password and authenticate users myself using a login form. The reason is that other applications may connect to this database from a context where Windows authentication is not an option (FileMaker Server for instance).

I have found myriad discussions that cover this issue from one angle or another, but none that have actually enabled me to implement a solution. I do not have a lot of VBA or LDAP experience but I know this must be possible.

So, what I want to do is:

1. Ask the user for a username and password when they open the database.
2. Use that username and password to authenticate them
   against our LDAP server.
3. Proceed if it passes, fail if it does not.

Can someone sketch out how this works or point me to a resource that describes this?

Comment: what have you already tried? could you show us your code?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I've still got work to do before I start writing code. I'm really looking for a push in the right direction. Once I understand the outline of how this would be accomplished then I can muddle through the implementation and ask specific questions later.

Comment: The usual practice when Windows Authentication is not available is to use SQL Server authentication. That would mean that any application trying to use the database would be using the same authentication authority, so it seems to me that it would solve your problem. Is there some reason you're rejecting that as the way to go?

Comment: David, that's exactly what I want to do, but I guess I was trying to avoid setting up separate SQL Server accounts for each user. I want them to be able to log in using their LDAP credentials so I want to create one SQL server account for the application (or one for each application), then authenticate users myself from Access. I don't have a lot of experience setting up databases like this so I may be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: SQL Server authentication does NOT use Windows logons. That's the entire point! You control the user authentication in SQL Server, independent of Windows authentication. Indeed, SQL Server authentication is THE OPPOSITE of Windows Authentication in SQL Server...

Comment: So why can't you use Windows authentication and groups?   Just about any solution you come up will be either easily crackable or a lot of work with possible security holes.

Comment: I don't think SQL Server authentication is too vulnerable, so it seems the obvious choice when Windows Authentication is unavailable (i.e., no domain controller).

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to create a VBA procedure which loops through all of your linked tables and alters the connection string to embed the username and password from a login form.

You can get the syntax for the existing ODBC linked tables by going to the debug window and typing this:

```
? CurrentDb().TableDefs("My Table Name").Connect
```

Which should give you something similar to:

ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=MYSQLSERVER001;UID=JPARKER;PWD=Pizza123;APP=2007 Microsoft Office system;DATABASE=MyDatabaseName

So your login form would capture the user name and password from the user, then store those as variables and use to build a new connection string.  Then iterate through the tabledefs collection updating the connect property.  Happens pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks Jim! This would obviate the need to deal with LDAP at all.

Comment: Note that the password is now visible in the connect string to anyone who can take the database home to a retail version of Access and run five lines of VBA code.